# Yii2 - how to get the selected value from DepDrop

Tags: yii2, selected

I use this module http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop
And this is my code:

_form:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'categories')->dropDownList($catList, ['id'=>'cat_name', 'prompt'=>'Select category']);?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'subcategories')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
            'options'=>['id'=>'sub_name'], 
            'pluginOptions'=>[
            'depends'=>['cat_name'],
            'placeholder'=>'Select subcategory',
            'url'=>  Url::to(['ad/subcat'])
            ]
            ]);  ?>
```

and controller:

```
public function actionSubcat() {
$out = [];
if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
$parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];

if ($parents != null) {
$id = $parents[0];
$out=\backend\models\Subcategories:find()->where(['cat_name'=>$id])->select(['id','sub_name AS name'])->asArray()->all();
echo Json::encode(['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>'']);
return;
}
}
echo Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'selected'=>'']);
}
```

And it works fine, but I would like to show or hide DIV depending on the selected subcategory.

And this is my code:
And this is my code:

```
 <?php $this->registerJs(' $(\'select[id="sub_name"]\').change(function(){

    if ($(\'option:selected\').val() == 3)

       document.getElementById("table").style.display = "block";
    else 
       document.getElementById("table").style.display = "none";

    });', View::POS_READY);
    ?>
```

But it does not work, it takes the value from category dropdown list.
How do I get the value from the selected sub-category?